# Issue rendering ReactJS CRUD components in Rails app with Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

I'm attempting to add CRUD functionality for a Rails resource through some ReactJS components.  I am using webpacker.

At this stage, I get one error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

My set up is:

React files are in `app/javascript/Botanicals`. I then have a `app/javascript/packs` where webpacker is compiling from into `app/public/packs/manifest.json`

My pack file is rendering the components:

**app/javascript/packs/botanicalsCRUD.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Botanicals from 'Botanicals'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("botanicals");
    ReactDOM.render(<Botanicals />, element);
});
```

I then individual files:

**app/javascript/Botanicals/index.jsx**

```
var Botanicals = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Body />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Botanicals
```

**app/javascript/Botanicals/body.js.jsx**

```
var Body = React.createClass({


    getInitialState(){
        return { botanicals: [] };
    },

    componentDidMount(){
        $.getJSON('/botanicals.json', (response) => { 
            this.setState({ botanicals: response }); 
        });
    },

    handleSubmit(item) {
        var newState = this.state.botanicals.concat(botanical);
        this.setState({ botanicals: newState })
    },

    handleDelete(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: `/botanicals/%{id}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: () => {
                this.removeItemClient(id);            
            }
        });
    },

    removeItemClient(id) {
        var newBotanicals = this.state.botanicals.filter((botanical) => {
            return botanical.id != id;
        });

        this.setState({ botanicals: newBotanicals });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NewItem handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
                <AllItems botanicals={this.state.botanicals} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Body
```

**app/javascript/Botanicals/newitem.js.jsx**

```
var NewItem = React.createClass({

    handleClick() {
        var name = this.refs.name.value;
        var description = this.refs.description.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/botanicals",
            type: "POST",
            data: { botanical: { name: name, description: description } },
            success: botanical => {
                this.props.handleSubmit(botanical);
            }
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref='name' placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
                <input ref='description' placeholder='Enter a description' />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default NewItem
```

**app/javascript/Botanicals/allitems.js.jsx**

```
var AllItems = React.createClass ({
    handleDelete(id) {
        this.props.handleDelete(id);
    },

    render() {
        var botanicals = this.props.botanicals.map((botanical) => {
        return (
            <div key={botanical.id}>
                <h3>{botanical.name}</h3>
                <p>{botanical.description}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, botanical.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        );
    });

            return <div>{botanicals}</div>;
        }
    });

export default AllItems
```

**views/botanicals/index.html.erb**

```
<% javascript_pack_tag 'botanicalsCRUD' %>

<h1>Botanicals</h1>

<div id="botanicals"></div>
```

BotanicalsCRUD is in the `manifest.json` file:

```
 "botanicalsCRUD.js": "/packs/botanicalsCRUD-b8ea47dea15aa535c997.js",
  "botanicalsCRUD.js.map": "/packs/botanicalsCRUD-b8ea47dea15aa535c997.js.map",
```

My main suspicion is that render file in `Packs` isn't correctly finding `botanicals/index.jsx`.

I'm struggeling with the fact there isn't more error messages.

Answer (score 0):

you should put `<% javascript_pack_tag %>` inside a div with the same id as you wrote in `getElementById` of your first react file.

that's mean in views/botanicals/index.html.erb you should write

```
<div id="botanicals">
   <% javascript_pack_tag 'botanicalsCRUD' %>
</div>
```

hope it will work for you